# How to Schedule a task for future execution in Task Parallel Library

Tags: .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Is there a way to schedule a Task for execution in the future using the Task Parallel Library?

I realize I could do this with pre-.NET4 methods such as System.Threading.Timer ... however if there is a TPL way to do this I'd rather stay within the design of the framework.  I am not able to find one however.

Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

This feature was introduced in the [Async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=18712f38-fcd2-4e9f-9028-8373dc5732b2&displaylang=en), which has now been rolled into .NET 4.5. Doing it as follows does not block the thread, but returns a Task which will execute in the future.

```
Task<MyType> new_task = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                            .ContinueWith<MyType>( /*...*/ );
```

(If using the old Async releases, use the static class `TaskEx` instead of `Task`)

Comment: Or simply await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: +1, but any non-sleep alternative for .NET 4? (I'm using a little bit over-engineered approach using single thread with heap-based priority queue which just starts new tasks when their time comes, over-engineered as priority queue management is not free)

Comment: @MiloszKrajewski `Task.Delay` does not sleep! Generally, sleeping a `Task` (thread) defeats the design purpose and philosophy of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` entirely, and is not recommended. Sleeping would never be the basis of a built-in `.NET` API like `Task.Delay`; rather it relies on the scheduler in the OS kernel to create a task which doesn't execute until the delay has expired. Also, Chris proposed `await`, in which case `Delay` may not even end up using an extra thread at all, since `async`/`await` allow single threads to contribute forward progress on multiple "blocked" operations.

Comment: @GlennSlayden I know it's ancient history now, but you missed one bit of information, I said: ".NET 4". `Task.Delay` is .NET 4.5. Or to put it differently "alternative in .NET 4 not using Sleep". Doesn't matter anymore though. Already switched to .NET 4.6.

Comment: @MiloszKrajewski Indeed 'ancient history'--and it would have required your project to allow the use of preview code--but wouldn't it have been possible to run the "Async CTP" (that I mentioned in the original reply) on top of .NET 4?

Answer (score 11):

You can write your own RunDelayed function. This takes a delay and a function to run after the delay completes.

```
    public static Task<T> RunDelayed<T>(int millisecondsDelay, Func<T> func)
    {
        if(func == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("func");
        }
        if (millisecondsDelay < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("millisecondsDelay");
        }

        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        var timer = new Timer(self =>
        {
            ((Timer) self).Dispose();
            try
            {
                var result = func();
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.SetException(exception);
            }
        });
        timer.Change(millisecondsDelay, millisecondsDelay);

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
    public void UseRunDelayed()
    {
        var task = RunDelayed(500, () => "Hello");
        task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result));
    }
```

Comment: I believe your timer could be garbage collected prior to executing since you have no external reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

Set a one-shot timer that, when fired, starts the task.  For example, the code below will wait five minutes before starting the task.

```
TimeSpan TimeToWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
Timer t = new Timer((s) =>
    {
        // start the task here
    }, null, TimeToWait, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
```

The `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)` makes the timer a one-shot rather than a periodic timer.

Comment: Does that work?  Seems like the timer could get GCd after it went out of scope, and before my event fired...   In any case, I was hoping for something native to TPL (for example, taking a task as an argument and allowing Task maangement), which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Yes, in that example the timer could get collected. Declare the Timer reference at a scope that will prevent premature collection.

Comment: OK - thank you for your answer.  I mentioned in the question that a timer would work; i was hoping for something that dealt with Task objects natively.  Thank you though!